# define Y-axis values in glMDplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rna-seq

Following is the code I qm using to generate three different combinations of glMDplots, but the y axis values are adjusting on its own, and thus comparison is not that visible.

````
for(i in 1:3)
  {
  Cl <- colnames(summary(decideTests(fit2)))[i]
  glMDPlot(fit2,coef=i, counts=logCPM.filt, anno=d.filt$genes[,2:3], groups=group, samples=targets$Label, transform=F, 
           status=decideTests(fit2), main=paste0("MD plot: ", "Treated vs Untreated in ",Cl), sample.cols = targets$col,
           html=Cl ,folder="Treated_vs_Untreated_stranded", launch=TRUE)
  } ```





i have tried adding the
 yrange=c(-2.0 ,2), 
 rescale.axis=F, 

but there is no change its the same.
The y axis scale is like (-1.5 ,- 2),(-1.2 , 1.4) and (-1,1.5) but I want to fix it as (-2 , 2)
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal reproducible example and format your question to separate code and questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example